# Elegant way to change control visibility in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I find more questions on this theme, but I not find answer.

I need to changing visibility on control click.

In win form app, if I am right, I can use something like:

```
somecontrol.Visible = !somecontrol.Visible;
```

But when app is `wpf` I cannot use this way.

Is there way to do this on something "elegant" way then `if-else`?

Thanx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In WPF UIElement.Visibility has 3 states; Visible/Hidden/Collapsed.

If hidden, the control will still affect the layout of surrounding controls, elements that have a Visibility value of Collapsed do not occupy any layout space.

You can switch between visible and hidden or collapsed.

```
somecontrol.Visibility = somecontrol.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 4):

In WPF the property you're trying to change is called **Visibility** u can use it as described below..

```
uiElement.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    // Visibility.Collapsed;
                    // Visibility.Visible;
```

The states interact like @Glen already mentioned.
What do you mean by..

> Is there way to do this on something "elegant" way then if-else?

If you don't want to write the whole construct just use the shorter form..

```
uiElement.Visibility = uiElement.Visibility == Visibility.Visible // condition
    ? Visibility.Collapsed // if-case
    : Visibility.Visible;  // else-case
```

Answer (score 2):

Natural option in the context of WPF is to use an MVVM pattern. So you have a control like

```
<Button Content="I'm a button"
        Visibility={Binding BtnVis} />
```

And in your DataContext you would have a public property which you can set at your wish.

```
class DataContext
{
    public Visibility BtnVis { get; set; }
}
```

Another usual option is to make use of a converter because, maybe, in your ViewModel you would like to have a bool property, not an `UIElement.Visibility` one.

Comment: Never forget to mention that `class DataContext` would have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.